# hibernate search configuration

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search, elasticsearch-mapping

Im using hibernate search and elastic search as backend . When i config hibernate and hibernatesearch in xml file  everything is ok but whene i config it in java class this warning occur and nothing found in my search .
xml config is:

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3399/elastic" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager" value="elasticsearch"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host" value="http://127.0.0.1:9400"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy" value="CREATE"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status" value="YELLOW"/>

    </properties>
```

java class config is :

```
java.util.Properties settings = new java.util.Properties();
            settings.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            settings.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3399/elastic");
            settings.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.USER, "admin");
            settings.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.PASS, "admin");
           settings.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT,"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
            settings.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
            settings.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
            settings.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.POOL_SIZE, "5");
settings.put("hibernate.search.default.indexmanager", "elasticsearch");
            settings.put("hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host", "http://127.0.0.1:9400");
            settings.put("hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy", "CREATE");
            settings.put("hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status", "YELLOW");
```

Warning is :

> WARNING: request [HEAD http://127.0.0.1:9400/com.radar.elasticsearch.videogame] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-6.8.0-65b6179 "[types removal] The parameter include_type_name should be explicitly specified in get indices requests to prepare for 7.0. In 7.0 include_type_name will default to 'false', which means responses will omit the type name in mapping definitions."]

Answer (score 0):

You are using Elasticsearch 6.8 where `types` are deprecated. Please refer [removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) for more info,

You need to pass `_doc` instead of type name otherwise use `include_type_name` if you are using your own `type` name in all the API.

Please refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0) official blog for more info

> If you plan to upgrade without downtime in a rolling fashion, you
>   should upgrade to 6.8 first, which is the only 6.x release to have
>   some features like support for the include_type_name parameter, which
>   is required to upgrade to 7.0 smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch support in Hibernate Search 5 is experimental and was only tested with Elasticsearch up to version 5.6.

If you need to upgrade to Elasticsearch 7, upgrade to Hibernate Search 6.
Hibernate Search 6 is currently in Beta but offers revamped APIs that will be a much better fit for Elasticsearch.

It also offers new features not found in Hibernate Search 5, such as support for [nested documents](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-storage) or the ability to [inject JSON directly into your query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-extensions-elasticsearch-from-json) (to take advantage of more exotic predicates/sorts/etc. not yet supported by the Hibernate Search DSL).

**EDIT**: Also, you can find information about the compatibility of Hibernate Search with various other components [on this page of the official website](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix).